# ASPXComboBox always show Guid.Empty at the First item

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I created an ASP page, added an aspx `ComboBox` and set the datasource.

```
<dx:ASPxComboBox ID="flStudentState"
                 runat="server"
                 DataSourceID="dcStudentState"
                 TextField="Value"
                 ValueType="System.Guid"
                 ValueField="LookUpValueId">
    <ValidationSettings>
        <RequiredField IsRequired="True" />
    </ValidationSettings>
</dx:ASPxComboBox>
```

but when I run my page the result is shown as:

[image]

Comment: Presumably that's the first data record to which it is bound?

Comment: You're not showing the data source with `ID="dcStudentState"` here. What query you've used to show GUID values from `LookUpValueId`?